# How can I stream Kinect V2 tracking data from PC to Raspberry Pi 3 through WiFi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, kinect, raspberry-pi3, kinect-v2, libfreenect2

I'm currently working with Kinect v2. I can do all sort of stuff on PC with it. What I want to do next is, to get the data I want on PC and control the Raspberry Pi with that data (for example, I will move the Pi with motors when I tilt my head to right). I have sorted out the motors and everything but I just don't know how to use that tracking data I have on PC to control the Pi.

I hope the question makes sense, i'm just extremely new to both Pi and Kinect.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to choose the bus that will connect the
PC to the Raspberry PI.

Your options are:

- Serial bus: [Pi Serial tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Read-and-write-from-serial-port-with-Raspberry-Pi/),[USB Serial to Pi cable](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/RPi.htm)
- Network Socket (cable/wifi): [Socket client/server c++ examples](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/sockets_server_client.php)
- i2c: [i2c windows PC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39244/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-interact-with-an-i2c-peripheral), [Configuring i2c on Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c)

I believe that the i2c or serial bus will be the easiest to start
with. But in the end all 3 options need to set up the connection, and send and receive bytes / byteArrays.

Comment: I used network socket approach only and managed to do what I wanted to do. Thanks for the answer.